# List.IndexOf(x) : Error => No overload for method 'IndexOf' takes 1 arguments in c#

Tags: c#

I do not understand this error, I searched the internet but I am told to do this:

```cs
int ender = Array.IndexOf(inList, ";")
```

But I don't use an "Array" I want to search in a list ...

My code:

```cs
myIntList.IndexOf(myInt) == -1)
```

Comment: It's impossible for us to answer without knowing more details. What is `neighbours`? Your code doesn't match the error message either. Your code passes 2 parameters but the error says 1.

Comment: Please consider giving us a [mre]

Comment: I think the documentation is pretty clear: [List<T>.IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.indexof?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but what is `myIntList` now? And what you show here doesn't compile.

Comment: it's just a list of int whatever it is that doesn't work :/

Comment: So it's a `List<int>`? Or an array of `int`? You need to be specific, please be more careful when posting on here

Comment: I plugged in these two lines of code at .Net Fiddle and it works fine: `List<int> myints = new List<int>{ 2, 4, 8, 12, 16};
Console.WriteLine(myints.IndexOf(8));`. There is no reason you shouldn't be able to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not confuse the static methods in the [Array Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?view=net-5.0) that must be used in conjunction with arrays and the instance methods of the [List<T> Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-5.0).

```cs
    var array = new string[] { "a", "b", ";", "," };
    int i = Array.IndexOf(array, ";");


    var list = new List<string> { "a", "b", ";", "," };
    int j = list.IndexOf(";");
```

Since `Array.IndexOf` is a static method, you must pass it an array as the first parameter, where as `List<T>.IndexOf` is called on a `List<T>` instance (i.e., on an object of that type), and therefore such a parameter is not required.

See also:

- [Array.IndexOf(Array, Object)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=net-5.0#System_Array_IndexOf_System_Array_System_Object_).
- [List<T>.IndexOf(T)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.indexof?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_IndexOf__0_).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an Array instead of a List, here's how you should use [IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=net-5.0):

```
Array.IndexOf(myIntList, myInt)
```

Answer (score -1):

indexOf() is used in javascript for checking if some pattern is contained in a string.

In C# you use Contains().

Comment: This isn't an answer, it's a comment.

Comment: Agree. This is not an answer. And it's not too hard to find the documentation on this method: [List<T>.IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.indexof?view=net-5.0)

Comment: you may well be right. still new to proper stackoverflow manners.

Comment: oh Contains works perfectly for my job thank you!

Comment: No problem, you can delete this answer and go get the 21 rep required to makes comments. It will only take a short while.

Comment: But it transformed into the answer??? Am now confused...

Comment: The doc exemple doesn't work with my code :( but Contains() do the job

Comment: @krisam maybe clean up the answer little bit. Provide example and link to documentation

Comment: Your answer doesn't answer the question that was asked, it just gives an alternate method.

Comment: the site doesn't want me to delete the post :(

Comment: it's true that it's not an answer but it still solves my problem ...

Comment: Sure, but the first line is just incorrect, that method does exist in the framework. The fact @krisam accidentally gave you an answer that worked is just plain lucky.

Comment: And now mentioning Javascript that isn't relevant at all. @krisam, the `IndexOf` method DOES exist, `Contains` is another method that used for a *different* purpose.

Comment: @DavidG, i hope you mean well, but remember you are answering to 2 people that are relatively new to stackoverflow etiquette. For me, just downgrade the post. I already edited the "answer" a little. It came from experience working both in javascript and C#. Not luck.

Comment: Except from what we are given, Contains is what the user wanted, he is comparing the IndexOf to -1, so this is both a better way to do it than IndexOf and a solution that worked for the OP.

The user is comparing IndexOf to -1, which means they want Contains

Comment: `IndexOf` gives you the position of the item you are looking for whereas `Contains` will just tell you if that item exists. They do different things. Nowhere in the original post does it suggest that is what OP wants, which is why I said you accidentally got the right answer.

Comment: If you look at the code provided by the OP, you **can** see that they wanted Contains, they are comparing to -1

Comment: @pevecg The question is asking about IndexOf and why it doesn't work. A good answer would be "Here's how IndexOf works and this is an example of how, oh, and as a bonus here's how you use Contains which is probably more appropriate to your solution"

Comment: I'm sure its not that important an issue. Thank you pevecg for defending my poor answering, and thank you DavidG for caring about discipline and the proper ways for answering. Just let it be.